# Blender 2.8 - render image creates only an outline of the image

Tags: rendering

In 2.8, I have a complete scene in blender that I would like to render as a 2D image (and save as a .png file).  I view the scene from the camera and the attempt to render.  When I click Render->Render Image, I don't get what appears in viewport, instead I get just a faint silhouette outline of what appears in viewport.  Render settings are all default.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render the scene as it is displayed in the 3D view, you'll have to set the render engine to *Workbench*. You can do this in render tab in Blender 2.8.

[image]

Otherwise when rendering with Cycles or Eevee you need to setup materials and lighting otherwise you won't be seeing much in your render.

Comment: how do I set the engine?

Comment: @vndep I've added an image that shows where.

Comment: Thanks - that moves things in the right direction.  However, the background image does not appear.  WHy is that?

Comment: @vndep What kind of background image? Are you talking about an environment texture or a reference image added through *Add > Image > Background*?

Comment: Added through add>image>background.

Comment: @vndep That is just meant as a reference image for modelling and can't be rendered as far as I'm aware (it's essentially an *Empty* that displays in image just for the viewport). You can add a plane though and apply the texture to it or make the film transparent and composite the render and your image afterwards.

Comment: I added a new question to address how to add the image through a plane.  See  "https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146090/blender-2-8-adding-an-image-to-a-scene"